# Possible to nest within &:before using SASS?

Tags: html, css, sass

Trying to use sass to position a sprite: [**CodePen Link**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JeEoC). I want to have each card show, but I can only get the visa one to show using the &:before method.  Can I not nest .visa/.mastercard/.amex in &:before?

```
<div class="saved_cc_block">
   <div class="saved_cc">
        <a class="cc_img visa"></a>
   </div>

   <div class="saved_cc">
        <a class="cc_img mastercard"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
.cc_img {
  position: relative;
  height: 26px;
  left: 9px;
  padding-left: 50px;

  &:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 41px;
    height: 26px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/3zRD5fn.png') no-repeat;

        .visa {
            background-position: 0;
        }
        .mastercard {
            background-position: -51px 0;
        }
        .amex {
            background-position: -102px 0;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: This would render to the CSS `.cc_img:before .visa { ... } ...` which isn't valid CSS, so SASS can't do this either. The `:before` and `:after` pseudo class denotes a _virtual_ element that appears in the element X, these can't contain children elements.

Comment: virtual -> [CSS generated content](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#gen-content)

Comment: Why would you expect you *could* do this?  Did you look at the compiled result?  Was it what you expected it to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:before` is a pseudo element, you can't nest other elements within it. I think you probably want to structure your css like this:

```
.cc_img {
    position: relative;
    height: 26px;
    left: 9px;
    padding-left: 50px;

    &:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 41px;
        height: 26px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 0;
        background: url('http://i.imgur.com/3zRD5fn.png') no-repeat;
    }
}

.visa:before {
    background-position: 0;
}
.mastercard:before {
    background-position: -51px 0;
}
.amex:before {
    background-position: -102px 0;
}
```

Comment: this didn't work for me, but worked when I put them completely outside of .cc_img

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

The elements with those class names are children of the cc_img div, not of the generated pseudo-element that appears before it. Psuedo-elements can't have child nodes.

Look at generating the psuedo-element before the link instead of before the div.